# Why does Float has a constructor that allows double as an argument while Double doesn't have a constructor with float as an argument in JAVA?

Tags: java

I read in a JAVA book that there are 3 constructors for Float(with args: String/float/double). While there are only 2 constructor for Double(with args String/double). So my question is, why doesn't Double has a constructor that takes float as an argument.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, or whether this is meant to be a self-answered question.

Comment: You most likely mess up *type casting* with *auto boxing*...

Comment: double is super-set of float.

Comment: I can compile code that passes either floating type to either constructor. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: Because `new Double(double)` can _already_ take a `float` due to **widening**.

Comment: Let's say this way - every float can be 'fit' into the double - vice versa isn't true...

Comment: or, in other words, Double constructor DOES ALLOW float as argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* you've said why in your question, but just for clarity:

`Double(double)` works just fine if you pass it a `float`, so there's no need for `Double(float)`. This is because in a [constructor invocation (JLS§5.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), a [widening primitive conversion (JLS§5.1.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) is allowed. `float` to `double` is a widening primitive conversion.

But `Float(float)` would *not* be just fine if you passed it a `double`; you'd get a warning of a loss of precision because that's a [*narrowing* primitive conversion (JLS§5.1.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). So by providing a `Float(double)` constructor which explicitly states it will lose precision, the API makes it possible to write code calling `Float`'s constructor with a `double` without the warning. *(You could argue whether that's a good thing vs. having callers do the explicit `(float)` cast when making the call, but...)*

Comment: It works just fine ... because a `float` will be automatically widened to a `double`.

Comment: @StephenC: I was going to cite the part of the JLS that covers this when answering, and have to admit in the two minutes I allocated to the task, I couldn't prove to myself that it was a [widening convesion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) per se vs. one of the 18 clauses around method selection (which would presumably then cite widening conversion). Purely out of academic interest if you happen to know the correct starting point in the method (constructor) selection, I'd be keen to know. But not if it's a bother. :-)

Comment: OK.  Per 5.1.2 float -> double is a "widening primitive conversion".  Per 5.3 "Loose invocation contexts" allow widening primitive conversions.  Per 15.12.2.3 ("Phase 2: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Loose Invocation ") - *"If m is not a generic method, then m is applicable by loose invocation if, for 1 ≤ i ≤ n, either e<sub>i</sub> is compatible in a loose invocation context with F<sub>i</sub> (§5.3) or e<sub>i</sub> is not pertinent to applicability."*